# Php mysql update puts in blank space

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so i have a problem here. I solved the updating to a mysql database with just set values. But now i want to let the user put something by use of a textbox to update a row.
this doesnt seem to work

code:

```
$newfirstname = $_POST['newfirstname'];

        //Update the record
        $updateQuery = "UPDATE users SET firstname = '".$newfirstname."' WHERE KcID = 2";
        mysql_query($updateQuery) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
        //create the query
        $query = mysql_query("select * from voskousers");

        //return the array and loop through each row
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
    ?>
```

It just doesnt update it with the right value, it makes it a blank space in my row.

Comment: Is your form element named? I.e.: `name="newfirstname"` which is most likely the issue or you have a typo in your form element.

Comment: Show your full code including HTML form. There are too many things at play. Plus, make sure your `KcID` column exists and is an `int` with a value of 2.

Comment: echo the post (newfirstname) before you update and see if its been passed.

Comment: The usual comment about: please stop using the 'mysql_*' functions 'cos they are 'not good'. I will be recommending using PDO from here on in as even 'mysqli' is rather limited.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you're updating a table called **users** but then selecting from a table called **voskousers**?